# What is currently the longest commercial flight in terms of distance?

Tags: aviation-history

Flightradar24 has [announced few hours ago](https://twitter.com/flightradar24/status/601590237752664065), that Qantas QF7 is taking off for its 13,804 km long flight and named it *the longest commercial flight (by distance)*.

Is that correct? I was more than sure, that I heard few years ago, that current record belongs to Singapore Airlines, that has at least one commercial route of a little bit more than 14k kilometers.

Comment: Today I read [this article on Aviation Week](http://aviationweek.com/commercial-aviation/ultra-long-haul-who-s-flying-where#slide-0-field_images-1425121) on ultra-Long Range routes, and I remember this conversation, I just wanted to contribute!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-stop_flight#Discontinued), the flight you are referring to, SQ21, got discontinued in November 2013. The runner up, still from Singapore Airlines, SQ37, got discontinued one month earlier.

The [same page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_flights#By_great_circle_distance) reports that <strike>QF8 is the current holder of the title of "longest non-stop flight" and has the same destinations as today's QF7</strike> as of [February 2017](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-35710969) Qatar Airways flights 920/921, covering 14,534 km (7,848nm / 9,031mi) from [Doha, Qatar (DOH/OTBD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doha_International_Airport) to [Auckland, New Zealand (AKL/NZAA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Airport), beats QF8 by about 395 NM.

If we instead include 1-time-only flight by a commercial airliner, the longest one has been flown in [November 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_distance_record#Commercial_aircraft) between Hong Kong and London, as a [demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20191203173757/http://www.seattlepi.com/business/article/Flight-distance-record-awaits-as-big-777-heads-to-1187040.php) by Boeing.

The title of absolute longest flight without refueling is instead held by a [non-commercial flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_distance_record#Non-commercial_powered_aircraft) done in an aircraft specifically built for the purpose.

Comment: Your answer (and my question) is about commercial, repeatable route. Just a small notice, from the article you linked to, about a longest, world record, single passenger flight: "_On 9 November 2005 a Boeing 777-200LR, dubbed the Worldliner, completed the world's longest non-stop passenger flight. It traveled 21,602 kilometres (11,664 nmi) eastward, as opposed to a normal westward routing for that sector, which is much shorter at 9,647 kilometres (5,209 nmi), from Hong Kong to London, in roughly 22 h 22 min_" .

Comment: @trejder you're right, I updated the answer including also the absolute longest flight

Comment: Wait - the november 2005 flight WAS NOT a commercial, passenger-carrying flight. (It was not a charter or anything.)  It was just a demo by Boeing, carrying only Boeing staff, journalists etc.  Added an article link.  Note that the wiki page confusingly reads "commercial aircraft" but mixes in that list one-off non-paying-passenger flights, with various demonstrations and tests

Comment: @JoeBlow Well it was a commercial aircraft, as distinct from a military, prototype or experimental aircraft. It just wasn't in commercial service that day.

Comment: Hey David - sure, it was a commercial aircraft, not a commercial "FLIGHT" - note the question title.  I was just pointing out it's a little confusing. The question is very much about longest "flight" in the sense of airline routes (not experimental aircraft, etc).

Comment: At this moment the longest route is EK448/449 between dubai and Auckland, start services 2days ago. But it will soon be surpassed by UA1/2 between Singapore and San Francisco

Comment: I heard also that Emirates is planning a non-stop flight from Dubai to Panama City.

Comment: Today I read [this article on Aviation Week](http://aviationweek.com/commercial-aviation/ultra-long-haul-who-s-flying-where#slide-0-field_images-1425121) on ultra-Long Range routes, and I remember this conversation, I just wanted to contribute!

Comment: @Him SQ now also flies SFO-SIN direct. They're also planning to restart the SIN-NYC service next year and, if I understand correctly, also start a direct service to LAX.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this CNN article](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/coronavirus-worlds-longest-flight/index.html), the record has been broken because of the COVID-19 outbreak:

> On March 14, French airline Air Tahiti Nui flew the longest ever scheduled passenger flight by distance -- transiting 9,765 miles across the world from Papeete, in Tahiti, French Polynesia, to Paris' Charles de Gaulle airport.
>
> This one off milestone was a direct consequence of the coronavirus-induced US travel restrictions.
>
> This route usually involves a scheduled stopover at Los Angeles International Airport (LAX). But when an airplane stops over in the US, all passengers must alight the aircraft and proceed through US Customs and Border Protection before they're allowed to advance on with the next leg of their journey.
>
> Current restrictions rendered this part of the journey untenable, so instead, flight TN064 just carried straight on, departing at 3 a.m. local time from Papeete airport and arriving in Paris at 6:30 a.m. local time on March 15.

This *is* a scheduled flight, but a one time deviation from the schedule (though the situation may continue to be like this in the near future).

Comment: "Going forward, the flights are planned to use Vancouver as a transit point." ([gcmap.com](http://www.gcmap.com/featured/20200316)) Sounds like it was a one time deviation.

Comment: Agreed, I'm not sure this counts as a regularly scheduled commercial flight.

Answer (score 2):

Air India 173 flies over Pacific some times. It often travells 9500 miles+ in 15 hours. 
On 21st October 2016, it flew 10,204 miles (16,480 km).

[Source](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/AIC173/history/20161020/2200Z/VIDP/KSFO)

Comment: True, though most of the others are measuring "longest flight" by the shortest-path distance between the city pair rather than by actual distance flown, since all airline flights can significantly change course from one day to the next (due to weather, winds aloft, turbulence, TFRs, traffic, etc.) For measuring longest airline route, distance between the city-pair is a more useful measure, as it doesn't change from day to day (well, not unless you take continental drift or the effects of large earthquakes into account.)

Comment: @reirab LOL! I think that even "continental drift or the effects of large earthquakes" doesn't have that significant influence into airline route, after all! :>

Comment: @trejder They might, if said continental drift or earthquakes coincide with certain other types of geological activity. :-)